Simple html & css - div doesn't cover the inner div
Is there a way to modify the container class with css so that spinner looks inside the container (the container has the dynamic height to be more or equal the spinner height)?


.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.spinner {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.spinner::before {
  content: "Why this text is not inside green";
  font-size: 24px;

}
<div class="container">
  <div class="spinner">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
Why this text is not below another text?
</div>




That's basic understanding on how position: absolute; works MDN: position: absolute

Please make your question a little more clear, what exactly do you wanna achieve?

Consider using a grid with the contents super-centered and not needing the absolute positioning.  The grid then adjusts to the content size.


.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.spinner {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.spinner::before {
  content: "Why this text is not inside green";
  font-size: 24px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="spinner">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  Why this text is not below another text?
</div>




Here's the description of answer given by – Roko C. Buljan in comments
just update your container class to:
.container {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

The .spinner element is taken out of the normal document flow and positioned absolutely. This is done so that it will be placed at a specific location within its containing element.

Your .container should have position: relative so the .spinner will be relative to the .container


    .container {
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid green;
    }

    .spinner {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .spinner:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "Why this text is not inside green";
      font-size: 24px;
      
      left: 80px; 
      color:#FFBC00;
      border: 2px solid blue;
    }
    <div class="container">
      container
      <div class="spinner">
        spinner
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    Why this text is not below another text?
    </div>




Does this answer the question? Still not inside the green.

is this what are you trying to achieve ?
i changed the positioning: .spinner is now correctly positioned relative to the .container.
and added container Flexibility: The .container can have dynamic height, and the spinner will stay centered.


.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative; 
  min-height: 100px; 
}

.spinner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.spinner::before {
  content: "Why this text is not inside green";
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="spinner"></div>
</div>
<div>
  Why this text is not below another text?
</div>



